# Network and Memory Statistics

Tags: networking, memory

I want to know network and memory usages during a specific period let say for the past 1 hour. Is there any command or anything to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sar` (system activity reporter) is a great tool to collect, report, or save system activity information over time.

**Installation:**

`yum -y install sysstat`
or
 `sudo apt-get install sysstat`